# ¿Cuándo debo marcar una publicación como "Muy baja calidad" (MBC)?

Tags: discusión, reportes, propuesta-de-faq

Entre las opciones para reportar una publicación se encuentra "Muy baja calidad" (MBC de aquí en adelante). ¿Cuándo debo utilizar ese tipo de reporte?

---

<sub>Esta pregunta viene motivada por el hecho de que, en general, considero que se está abusando de los reportes *MBC* en el sitio (son de lejos los reportes que mas se reciben). Con ella espero clarificar que se considera "muy baja calidad" y, posiblemente, reducir algo este tipo de reportes</sub>

Comment: Gran pregunta canónica la que creaste aquí. Lo mismo le podéis poner [meta-tag:destacado] de vez en cuando para que vaya calando

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' puede ser una buena idea, aunque la verdad no confío mucho en su eficacia. Lo pensaré ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**El reporte de una publicación como *MBC* debe reservarse exclusivamente a publicaciones que no tienen ningún sentido, y que no pueden salvarse de ninguna manera mediante su edición.**

Una publicación que sólo contiene código es una publicación de baja calidad, pero **no** de **muy baja calidad**, por ejemplo.

Cuando un usuario reporta una publicación como *MBC*, lo que está pidiendo es su inmediata eliminación, bien por los usuarios con privilegios de moderación en esa cola, bien por los moderadores. Si la publicación se puede salvar mediante su edición, no debería reportarse como *MBC*.

En general, si hablamos de respuestas, debe usarse solo en casos de repuestas que no tengan absolutamente ningún sentido, o tal vez si la respuesta es simplemente un enlace sin ningún contenido más (incluso en esos casos, yo preferiría un comentario al autor pidiendo que agregara las partes relevantes del enlace en su respuesta para salvar la publicación).

**No debe usarse para respuestas incorrectas, cortas, o que solo responden parcialmente a la pregunta planteada.**

---

<sub>Esta respuesta esta basada en las respuestas de [esta pregunta de meta en Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338887/579895) y en mis propias opiniones. Está abierta a discusión y a edición para mejorarla o ampliarla</sub>

Comment: Premio para el que cuente cuantas veces he escrito _"muy baja calidad"_ :)

Comment: 9 si contamos está ultima del comentario :D

Comment: @x3k_js creo que olvidaste el título? ;)

Comment: *MBC* de aquí en adelante...

Comment: @PabloLozano gran idea. MBC debe ser

Answer (score 2):

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando un usuario levanta un reporte MBC?

1. El reporte aparece en la cola de reportes de los moderadores diamantados. Este es el único efecto que es seguro que tenga un reporte MBC. Sin embargo, hay un pequeño retraso (no he encontrado el tiempo exacto en caso de Stack Overflow en español, pero creo que es de 1 hora) antes de que los moderadores la veamos, para permitir que sea la propia comunidad la que se encargue del tema.
2. Si una publicación nunca ha estado en la cola de MBC, levantar el reporte la colocará en dicha cola.
   Si la publicación ya tuvo un reporte previo del mismo tipo que fue resuelto descartándolo, volver a reportar por la misma razón no lo llevará a la cola MBC, pero sí que aparecerá en la cola de moderadores para que podamos hacernos cargo de ella.

---