# ¿Por qué algunos revisores de esta respuesta señalan que no es una respuesta?

Tags: discusión

Revisando algunas publicaciones encontre [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/328970/22539). La respuesta es corta, precisa y para mi es una respuesta correcta y de calidad ya que señala la causa del problema y señala tambien como solucionarlo pero algunos usuarios de 2k, 3k, 32k y 3k señalan que deben ser una edición de la pregunta.

Por lo anterior quizas el equivocado sea yo por lo que pregunto a la comunidad ¿Una respuesta corta no es de calidad? ¿Por qué esa respuesta debe ser una edición?. Si yo no estoy equivocado entonces la causa de esos comentarios es porque no hay un castigo a ese tipo de acciones incorrectas de la cola de revisión y por ello los usuarios no meditan correctamente sus acciones, si es asi ¿Qué acciones se pueden tomar para revertir ese problema?

---

**Nota 1:**

IMHO Una respuesta deber tener al menos una de las siguientes características: Explicar la causa del problema y/o proponer una solucion o *workaround*. La primera característica da a entender porque el código o problema se genera y en algunos problemas basta ya que por ejemplo la respuesta puede ser un "no, no se puede por X, Y o Z". La segunda característica tambien es de ayuda ya que señala como solucionar el problema ya que muchas veces no es posible explicar el problema y se responde: "No sé cual es la causa del error pero haciendo X, Y o Z funciona". Y la gran mayoria de las respuetas cumplen con ambos y se responde como: "La causa del problema es A, B y C y lo puedes solucionar haciendo X, Y y Z".

Aplicando lo anterior a la respuesta del OP se observa que tiene ambas características:

- Explicación de la causa del error: *En mi caso el path del proyecto tenía tildes*
- Solución o *workaround*: *Lo moví a una carpeta cuya ruta no tuviera tildes y me funcionó.*

**Nota 2:**

Algunos usuarios señalan que el AP debio marcar su respuesta como correcta pero por reglas de SO un usuario puede marcar su propia respuesta como correcta despues del segundo día de publicar su pregunta, y en este caso aun no se cumple esa condición.

**Nota 3:**

Mi pregunta no intenta pedir sancionar o castigar a ningun usuario en particular, asumiendo que la revision fuese un "error" y si lo hubiese hecho un solo usuario no me hubiese preocupado, para mi lo preocupante es que lo hicieron varios usuarios con alta reputación, si es asi podria llegar a la conclusión es que muchos no estamos atentos a las revisiones en la cola de revisión eliminando preguntas y/o respuesta buenas por un descuido.

Comment: En mi caso pensé que era una respuesta de otra persona, porque aclara que su ruta estaba con tildes, pero en la pregunta no hay ninguna tilde en su ruta. Me di cuenta y borré mi comentario.

Comment: @ArtEze aun asi fuese la respuesta de otro usuario para mi seria una respuesta, quizas no solucione el problema pero es una respuesta. En muchas publicaciones nuevos usuarios que se topan con el mismo problema muchas veces dicen: *Yo tuve el mismo problema pero ninguna solución me ayudo, despues encontre la siguiente solución*. Por otro lado tu no señalaste que no es una respuesta.

Comment: Sí, la confusión viene de ahí, el supuesto usuario nuevo tenía el mismo problema pero en su ruta tenía una tilde y lo solucionó. Voté para eliminarla por pensar que era un problema diferente. Quitarle la tilde no solucionaría la respuesta del usuario que preguntó. Luego al abrir el enlace de la pregunta noté que era el mismo usuario. Entonces me di cuenta que voté incorrectamente y borré mi comentario generado desde la cola de revisiones. Se puede ver aquí mi la revisión donde voté. https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/196607

Comment: Eso sí. Por cierto, últimamente vi que el usuario [jsdnlb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/124894/jsdnlb) a veces revisa bien y otras no.

Comment: @ArtEze 1) No toda respuesta debe solucionar el problema del AP, algunas señalan que otros usuarios tuvieron el mismo problema y muestran su propia solución, asi otro usuario que es atraido a ver la pregunta por el titulo tambien podria probar esa nueva soluición. 2) No quiero direccionar el problema a los usuarios en particular sino a que el sistema permite ello, si un usuario de >=2k que para mi es experimentado y debiese conocer bien las reglas de SO toma ese tipo de decisiones entonces que se puede exigir a los usuarios nuevos o temporales.

Comment: Es cierto. De todos modos la respuesta estaría más completa si pudiera hacerlo funcionar con carpetas con tildes. Yo hasta le pediría que marque como correcta su respuesta ya que no hay otras.

Comment: @ArtEze 1) Seria una mejor respuesta pero no tener esa capacidad no la hace un mala respuesta, quizas otro usuario puede publicar otra respuesta que hace funcionar para nombre de carpetas con o sin tilde. 2) Lo de marcar su respuesta como correcta es una decisión personal. 3) Para mi lo preocupante es que muchos usuarios experimentados tomen esa decisión ya que si fuese un usuario no habría muchos problemas pero al ser varios entonces hay un problema mayor por debajo.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo, es preocupante. Yo ya expliqué mi motivo, quizás cada uno tenga un motivo diferente por el que decidió votar de tal manera. Solo mira que cada uno eligió un motivo diferente de eliminación.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Estoy de acuerdo en parte contigo. Lo primero es tener en cuenta que crear un MWE no es una tarea sencilla, y aun es más complicada si el error es silencioso, por otro lado muchos usuarios por cuestiones de seguridad no exponen las rutas reales sino que usan rutas genericas. Yo pienso que aun es una respuesta correcta, lo malo es la pregunta por lo que hay posibles acciones: dar un downvote o editar la pregunta para hacer evidente la tilde.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior yo no creo que la revision haya sido correcta, lo correcto hubiese sido señalar: "En tu pregunta la ruta que señalas no lleva tilde por lo que deberias editar tu pregunta colocando una ruta con tilde para hacer evidente el error"

Comment: A mi, sin meterme en otras consideraciones, me sorprende que la respuesta te parezca _de calidad_. Personalmente considero que la respuesta es bastante pobre, e imagino que es lo que ha llevado a muchos revisores a marcarla como que "no es una respuesta"

Comment: @Pikoh Para ti ¿Qué características debe tener cualquier publicacion para ser una respuesta? ¿y si ya es una respuesta entonces que características debe tener para ser una respuesta de calidad? Para mi bastan las 2 características que señale en mi nota1 de mi pregunta. Para mi no es la mejor respuesta posible pero si la respuesta es de calidad, la mejor respuesta hubiese sido si la solucion haria que admitiera las tildes.

Comment: Estamos hablando de dos cosas. Para mi, es una respuesta. Pero no se puede considerar de calidad una sola frase explicando lo que le funcionó al op sin, por ejemplo, investigar y explicar porque razón python tiene un problema con las rutas que contienen tildes. Una respuesta de calidad no solo da la solucion al problema, sino que explica las causas para entender porqué la solución funciona, y desde luego en este caso no se cumple. Todo esto es por supuesto mi opinión.

Comment: Resumiendo, para mi el reporte es incorrecto, yo reportaría la respuesta como de _baja calidad_, no como _no es una respuesta_.

Comment: @Pikoh entiendo tu punto y agradezco tu comentario, la cuestion es primero delimitar el problema y entonces asi se podria delimitar la causa, por ejemplo el OP describio la causa del error: el uso de tildes en nombre rutas, obviamente otra respuesta podria describir porque la ruta con tildes causa errores pero va a depender de cuanta profundidad se requiere dar en una respuesta. Por ejemplo en un pregunta tipica de optimización de python muchas respuestas analizan el bytecode, otras hacen test con varias opciones, y cada uno es una respuesta con un enfoque distinto.

Comment: Efectivamente, pero para mi esa es la diferencia entre una respuesta(para mi esta **es** una respuesta) y una respuesta **de calidad**.

Comment: @Pikoh En eso estoy de acuerdo, es decir que para algunos puede ser solo una respuesta y para otros una respuesta de calidad, por lo que tu y yo estamos de acuerdo que al menos **es** una respuesta por lo que siendo asi yo no señalaria  que es de *baja calidad* y menos que *no es una respuesta*

Comment: Para mi si es de baja calidad, pero efectivamente no debería ser reportada de ninguna manera. Un reporte por baja calidad debe reservarse a respuestas que por su formato o contenido es casi imposible salvarlas. En este caso, mediante una edición podría mejorarse la respuesta sin ningun problema. En todo caso, si te parece que la respuesta es de baja calidad (como yo mismo pienso) para eso está el voto negativo.

Comment: @Pikoh Exacto, en mis años en SO nunca he reportado una respuesta como de baja calidad, y en esos casos lo más sencillo es darle un DV o hacer la edición necesaria para mejorarla.

Comment: Por cierto, relacionado hice una publicacion a finales del año pasado [reportes MBQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4434/15301) dado que encontraba muchos reportes de este tipo que debía rechazar, creo que por desconocimiento de cuando se debe usar ese tipo de reportes. Creo que con no es una respuesta pasa algo similar.

Comment: Y, como imaginaba, tambien hay una publicación sobre [cuando reportar como no es una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2973/15301)

Comment: Curioso, en SO el autor publicó la misma pregunta y respuesta y tuvo un +1 en la respuesta. Al ser usuario con algún punto ya, la respuesta no entró en Baja calidad ([está aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60195882/1983854)).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Ese mismo comportamiento yo esperaba en SOes(no necesariamente el UV)

Comment: ¿Qué es el UV, @eyllanesc?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' UV: upvote, DV: downvote :-)

Comment: Acabo de agregar [otra respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4604/15301) a la publicación anterior. Me parece especialmente relevante el último parrafo: _Cualquier publicación que intente responder a la pregunta -aunque sea mal- sigue siendo una respuesta_

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ¿Se puede enlazar esa pregunta que está en inglés con la pregunta que está en español?

Comment: @ArtEze te refieres a hacer la asociación de preguntas? Si es eso, no creo que sea oportuno: la pregunta no aporta demasiado.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Sí, me refería a eso. Bien, entiendo, mejor no.

Comment: @ArtEze a mí me parece que la asociación de preguntas es para casos recurrentes que tienen muchas visitas y queremos atraer a nuestro sitio. Pero como todo, siempre es susceptible de ser debatido :D

Comment: Añado: en SO la respuesta ha sido borrada por un moderador después de haber sido reportada por baja calidad ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60195883/timeline)).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Sí, es que debería ser cerrada por errores tipográficos. Son rápidos allá en SO en inglés.

Comment: @ArtEze la respuesta esta siendo borrado no por errores tipográficos sino como no reproducible.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sí, eso mismo, o puede ser las dos cosas al mismo tiempo. Me refería justamente a esa opción que hay para cerrar, no están separadas.

Comment: @ArtEze Aunque esten el mismo punto son 2 motivos diferentes, y en forma personal tiendo a diferenciarlos: en el caso de *problem that can no longer be reproduced* se refiere a que la información proveido por el OP no es suficiente para resolver el problema como claramente se observa en este caso, en el cao de *It's caused by a typo* claramente indica que fue error tipográfico trivial.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ahora que lo mencionas me doy cuenta que es cierto, es un error trivial, pero tampoco aclaró si estaba usando Windows o Linux, ya que las carpetas con tilde las trata diferente la consola en los dos sistemas.

Comment: @ArtEze pero eso debe ser una petición por parte de la comunidad, recalco: describir un problema es complicado, y peor si el error es silencioso.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ahora que veo bien esas barras invertidas significa que está usando Windows. En mi caso yo uso Linux.

Comment: @ArtEze yo pude reproducir el problema en mi consola de OSX. Crear un virtualenv en un directorio con tildes provoca el error de que `where python` no funcione. Por tanto, creo que la pregunta es legítima e interesante. Otra cosa es si _a mí me funciona haciendo otra cosa_ es válido como respuesta o no. Si alguien tiene que usar un directorio con tildes, claramente la solución no le servirá de nada. Si puede cambiar de nombre, pues sí.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Con esa explicación voy entendiendo mejor el asunto. Quizás deban restaurar la respuesta en SO en inglés. Aunque vi que en inglés tenía peor formato.

Answer (score 2):

Me gustaría que un moderador mande una captura de pantalla de mi comentario borrado o qué otros comentarios se borraron en esa pregunta.

Así puedo recordar mejor por cuál motivo voté para eliminarla y en el futuro tomar mejores acciones. No tomar una decisión tan pronto y mirar bien si el usuario es el mismo que preguntó para evitar confusiones.

En ese momento me di cuenta que mi voto fue incorrecto y por eso borré el comentario. Por curiosidad me gustaría saber en qué hora y minutos y segundos exactos borré mi comentario.

Answer (score 2):

<sup><sub>Ya que los comentarios se están alargando voy a poner aquí mi opinión y borrar los comentarios</sub></sup>

---

> ¿Por qué algunos revisores de esta respuesta señalan que no es una
>   respuesta?

Porque no responde a la pregunta. <sub>(flyes away)</sub>

---

Una respuesta que indica que el problema es la tilde de la ruta (que en la pregunta no existe) no es correcta. O en este caso "No es una respuesta" ya que realmente no responde a la pregunta indicada.

Pongamos otro ejemplo:

[pregunta]: ¿Por que mi contador no se incrementa cuando hago `cont++;` (código en el que se ve que utiliza `cont++;`).

[respuesta]: El problema era que no estaba haciendo `cont++;` añadiendo `cont++;` se arregla.

Pues efectivamente esto no es una respuesta. Es mas si el OP no se diera cuenta sería una pregunta que no se puede reproducir.

---

**Solución:** Indicarle al OP que su respuesta no responde a la pregunta ya que en la pregunta no se indica ninguna ruta con tilde y que para que sea valida debería de editar la pregunta.

Mas allá de si es o no una respuesta de calidad creo que ese tema se queda fuera de tu pregunta. Yo no la considero de calidad pero si considero que sea una respuesta útil.

Answer (score -2):

De la conversación con muchos usuarios de SOen y SOes he llegado a las siguientes conclusiones:

- La pregunta debe ser cerrada como: *Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos.*
- La respuesta no necesariamente debe ser correcta, si es incorrecta entonces lo recomendable es darlo un *downvote* y seguir nuestro camino, como [señala Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4601/por-qu%C3%A9-algunos-revisores-de-esta-respuesta-se%C3%B1alan-que-no-es-una-respuesta?noredirect=1#comment18940_4601): *Cualquier publicación que intente responder a la pregunta -aunque sea mal- sigue siendo una respuesta*. Es decir una publicación en la sección de respuesta para que sea válida vasta que intente dar una solución.
- Un moderador de SOen me señalo([see here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48595854#48595854)) respecto a la publicación en el sitio en inglés que es identica al del sitio en español: *I agree that shouldn't have been deleted. It was an answer. I undeleted it. If nothing else, it explains why the question was closed as a typo. I've also gone ahead and deleted the question; since the author has resolved their own problem, they don't need it anymore.* que claramente coincide con mis puntos anteriores.

Comment: En definitiva, ahora en SO está borrada ya que el OP soluciono su problema y se despreocupo de arreglar la pregunta. Pero aquí en SOes sigue la pregunta mal (el OP no creo que la modifique) y una respuesta que no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Sí pues. Si deseas que no suceda ello podrias 1) votar por cerrar esa pregunta o 2) Mejorar la pregunta. Como ves estan en nuestras manos.