# Reporte de respuestas TOTALMENTE erróneas

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, respuesta, reportes, eliminación-de-respuestas

Es un tema que ya he comentado con anterioridad en el chat y seguramente se ha tratado ya.

La conclusión ha sido siempre "vota negativo". Votar negativo me parece una solución cuando la respuesta no es del todo correcta o tiene problemas de calidad.

Pero creo que hay casos en los que votar negativo a una respuesta **erronea** no es suficiente. Considero que hay respuestas que hacen daño, por mucho que tengan negativos.

Hoy me han dado un ejemplo perfecto: [Al declarar una variable dentro de un if es considerada global scope?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334376/al-declarar-una-variable-dentro-de-un-if-es-considerada-global-scope)

En esa pregunta en pocos minutos recibió **3** respuestas erróneas. Y se cerró como duplicada (menos mal). Pero el daño ya está hecho, cualquier usuario nuevo que entre a esa pregunta por mucho que vea que tienen negativos va a ver que las 3 respuestas dicen lo mismo y claro, si veo 1 respuesta con negativos puede estar mal, ¿Pero las 3? (Igual han votado mal...)

El único reporte que puede ser algo parecido y que puede dar lugar a confusión es "No es una respuesta".
Pero según: [¿Cómo uso correctamente el reporte "No es una respuesta"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2973/c%c3%b3mo-uso-correctamente-el-reporte-no-es-una-respuesta/4604#4604), estas respuestas son "validas".

También está el reporte de muy baja calidad donde se habló de cuándo debería de usarse (y se indica que no se debe usar en estos casos): [¿Cuándo debo marcar una publicación como "Muy baja calidad" (MBC)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4434/cu%c3%a1ndo-debo-marcar-una-publicaci%c3%b3n-como-muy-baja-calidad-mbc/4435#4435)

---

**¿Debería de existir un reporte para respuestas totalmente erroneas?**

En caso negativo, **¿Se podría solicitar la eliminación de una pregunta/respuesta a un moderador de manera excepcional como este caso?**

---

Relacionado:

[Verifiquemos las respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4594/verifiquemos-las-respuestas)

[¿Debo borrar mi respuesta si se confirma que es errónea?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4462/debo-borrar-mi-respuesta-si-se-confirma-que-es-err%c3%b3nea)

Comment: Existe la opción Reportar -> Muy baja calidad.

Comment: @PabloLozano hmm..en realidad yo diría que no. Los reportes de MBC de hecho no se suelen usar correctamente, te remito a [¿Cuándo debo marcar una publicación como “Muy baja calidad” (MBC)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4435/15301).En cualquiera de estos casos, una edición de la respuesta podría hacerlas perfectamente válidas.

Comment: Sin embargo, uno de los enlaces dados como respuesta "correcta" y con 59 votos a favor, es incorrecta en varios puntos, que es una copia supuestamente extendida de la que sí es una respuesta correcta (el otro enlace).

Answer (score 5):

Empezando por el final: si, puedes solicitar la eliminación de cualquier publicación al equipo de moderación. Pero yo personalmente sería reticente a eliminar una respuesta por el hecho de ser incorrecta.

Si lo hiciésemos, nos convertiríamos en jueces de temas que en muchos casos no tenemos conocimientos suficientes para juzgar. Yo no tengo ni idea de python por ejemplo, e imaginemos que uno o varios usuarios solicitan la eliminación de una respuesta de python. Yo, como moderador, como podría juzgar si efectivamente la respuesta es incorrecta o no? El equipo de moderación no puede ser exigido a conocer todas las tecnologías que abarca el sitio.

Con lo que volvemos a que hacer en estos casos. Y yo creo que los votos negativos son suficientes. En el ejemplo que expones, todas las respuestas (al momento de esta publicación) tienen al menos 3 votos negativos. Cualquier usuario que llegue al sitio buscando una respuesta creo que sabrá entender que la comunidad ha determinado que las respuestas no son correctas (máxime cuando al tener tantos negativos su "brillo" se apaga.

Hay algo aún mejor, que en este caso no aplica al haber sido cerrada como duplicada: añadir una respuesta correcta. La comunidad la identificará asi, la votará positivamente y cualquier usuario la tomará como la respuesta correcta (o, al menos, más que las anteriores). Y la guinda del pastel es que el OP la acepte.

Resumiendo, creo que el sistema tal y como está es capaz de lidiar con estas situaciones mediante el sistema de votos y respuestas aceptadas.

Comment: 1. En el siguiente hilo en Ingles: [When or should you delete your incorrect answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/when-or-should-you-delete-your-incorrect-answer). Comenta que si nuestra respuesta es incorrecta deberíamos de borrarla en caso de que no aporte nada, ¿Por que no usar el mismo criterio para respuestas ajenas de usuarios que no las borran?.

Comment: 2. También está este otro hilo, que concuerda con tu opinión pero que no esta argumentado [Should I nominate incorrect answers for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143576/should-i-nominate-incorrect-answers-for-deletion) , donde ademas hablan de que hacer en las revisiones _Downvote and click "looks good", just for the irony of it ;)_ lo cual es bastante contradictorio. Ademas de el comentario que está en contra con bastantes votos a favor.

Comment: 1-Sencillo: una cosa es que tu borres tu propia publicación al darte cuenta de que no es correcta,y otra es que alguien externo lo juzgue y lo elimine,

Comment: Gran respuesta. No hay que involucrar a los moderadores en cosas que la comunidad ya puede gestionar y borrar respuestas es algo al alcance de los usuarios con cierta reputación: cuando tiene puntuación negstiva, una respuesta puede recibir votos de eliminación y queda eliminada cuando recibe 3.

Comment: +1 por esto: "Hay algo aún mejor, que en este caso no aplica al haber sido cerrada como duplicada: añadir una respuesta correcta"

Answer (score 5):

Ya existe un privilegio para esto: 
[Usuario de confianza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), actualmente obtenido al llegar a los 20 000 puntos.

Tal y como se lee en la página de ayuda:

> #### ¿Qué son los usuarios de confianza?
>
> Los usuarios de confianza pueden realizar acciones de confianza, entre ellas:
>
> - **Votar para eliminar respuestas con puntuación de -1 o inferior**
> - Votar para recuperar respuestas, excepto las eliminadas por un moderador
> - Votar para eliminar preguntas con un puntaje de -3 o menos inmediatamente después de ser cerradas
> - Edición de Wikis de etiquetas sin necesidad de aprobación

Por tanto, es simplemente cuestión de recomendar su uso a los usuarios con suficiente reputación.

---

Dicho lo cual, nunca está de más indicar en las respuestas por qué están mal y animar a sus autores a mejorarlas.

Comment: o.O Interesante... pero parece que solo se debería de votar la eliminación en casos de respuestas que "no son una respuesta" o de "muy baja calidad". Por lo que se sigue el criterio de los reportes. Por otro lado, ¿cuanto votos requieren? ¿5 como el cierre?

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior en [SO] yo lo uso con frecuencia, y he visto usar, para borrar respuestas malas o repetidas. Ayuda a mantener el sitio limpio. Necesita solamente 3 votos.

Comment: Más información en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/83)

Comment: Quisiera saber cuantos usuarios con reputación >= 20K existen en SOes :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc fácil, mira las ligas de reputación o el listado de usuarios

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Pues son solo 15 https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/alltime/es-stackoverflow/2015-12-01