# ¿Por qué el reporte de una respuesta fue rechazado?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, reportes

Iba a reportar una pregunta y me apareció el mensaje "Tu último reporte fue rechazado, por favor revísalo" referente a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407689/tengo-un-fatal-error-en-mi-c%c3%b3digo-de-php-que-no-logro-solucionar/407704#407704)

> Pues que seguramente el problema está en que quieres hacer un execute sobre el campo $email pero puede que no haya ningún $email.

Reporté como "No es una respuesta" por incluir "seguramente" y "puede que no haya", proporcionando solo **posibles escenarios** y no una solución en concreto; de hecho, hay comentarios de A. Cedano realmente bien elaborados y que, a fin de cuentas, fueron los que realmente llevaron al usuario a encontrar la solución.

La respuesta no cumple con lo especificado en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> **Contesta la pregunta**
>
> Lee la pregunta cuidadosamente. ¿Qué es lo que se está preguntando específicamente? **Asegurarte de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a esto. Y si no, provee una alternativa viable.** La respuesta puede ser “no hagas eso” pero debe también incluir “trata esto en vez”. Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta. La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores.

Veo que muchos usuarios se están esforzando por mejorar la calidad de preguntas y respuestas en SO, esperemos que su ánimo no decaiga y se pueda conseguir el objetivo de generar buenos contenidos.

**Edición:**

Para estar en mejor contexto acerca del reporte, de acuerdo al texto de

> **No es una respuesta**:
> *Posiblemente sea una edición, **un comentario**, otra pregunta, o se deba eliminar directamente.*

Gracias, **Pikoh**, por tomarte el tiempo para exponer tu punto de vista y aclarar el tema.

Comment: Tal vez muchos de los comentarios en esa pregunta podrían ser una respuesta un poco más elaborada. Al parecer ninguno de los que comentaron en la misma se tomaron el tiempo para redactar una respuesta. Quien sí lo hizo bien pudo ser más un comentario. Hasta allí todo igual. Lo que no sé realmente es el motivo del rechazo en el reporte, tengo entendido que es revisado por moderadores (y otros usuarios con más de 10K de rep, creo). De ser el caso, tal vez quien haya manejado el reporte no considera que dicha respuesta deba ser eliminada. Es mi especulación. Aunque tú y yo opinemos diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este caso, fui yo el que rechazó tu reporte.

A veces los moderadores nos encontramos en situaciones límite donde es complicado decidir si aceptar o no un reporte, dado que nuestra decisión puede eliminar directamente una publicación sin mas opinión que la nuestra.

En el caso que comentas la respuesta está aceptada, lo que ya retrae un poco de su eliminación ya que para el autor de la pregunta **si es una respuesta** que le ha servido.

Por otro lado, pensé que el problema de esa respuesta era una cuestión de redacción mas de que no fuera una respuesta. Si en lugar de "seguramente", "puede que"... la respuesta hubiera sido completamente afirmativa (*el problema está en que quieres hacer un execute sobre el campo $email pero no hay ningún $email*)..pensaríamos que no es una respuesta?

Es posible que mi decisión no haya sido correcta, pero como digo los moderadores tenemos que ser muy cuidadosos con las decisiones que tomamos. Y si, a veces (muchas probablemente) nos podemos equivocar.

Voy a aprovechar la ocasión para decir que nos encontramos con muchos reportes incorrectos también. Por poner algunos ejemplos: una respuesta incorrecta o de baja calidad **es una respuesta**, hay otros mecanismos para indicar que no lo es que un reporte como "no es una respuesta". Otro que nos encontramos mucho es "muy baja calidad". De este reporte se abusa mucho, ya que se debe restringir a casos muy específicos. En una ocasión traduje [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4434/15301) para tratar de que no se usase mal este reporte...con poco éxito la verdad.  Dejo aqui la clave de cuando usar este reporte:

> El reporte de una publicación como MBC debe reservarse **exclusivamente** a publicaciones **que no tienen ningún sentido**, y que **no pueden salvarse de ninguna manera mediante su edición**.

Perdón por la extensión de la respuesta y el desahogo. Espero que al menos así podáis entender un poco mejor la labor de los moderadores diamantados :)

Comment: Pikoh, entiendo perfectamente las problemáticas a las que se enfrentan los moderadores y, de hecho, algo me decía que la marca de aceptada podría ser un factor para rechazar el reporte. Me queda la certeza de que tomaste una decisión basada en tu buen criterio y experiencia, buscando lo que es mejor para la comunidad. Muchas gracias por responder y aclarar mi duda.

Comment: @Triby para eso estamos. No dudes en preguntarnos cualquier duda que te surja. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 4):

La bandera **No es una respuesta** solo se debe usar en los casos en que claramente no hay un interés en responder como por ejemplo:

- spam,
- insultos,
- señalar que tambien tiene el mismo problema,
- añadir información adicional a la pregunta porque claramente no es el sitio adecuado.
- bromas, etc.

En cambio si se critica por la calidad de la respuesta entonces lo que corresponde es dar un *upvote* o *downvote*, una edición o dejar un comentario.

---

Se debe tener en cuenta que una respuesta es un intento en dar una solución a un problema en especifíco, y basado en que es un intento puede ser:

- una respuesta incorrecta,
- una respuesta parcial,
- o una respuesta completa.

Y justamente la clasificación se muestra a traves de los votos de la comunidad y la aceptación de la respuesta por parte del AP.

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión; ya mencioné en otro comentario que no acostumbro a dar votos negativos y el criterio para reportar fue la última frase de "No es una respuesta": _Posiblemente sea una edición, **un comentario**, otra pregunta, o se deba eliminar directamente._

Comment: @Triby Indicar que una respuesta es un comentario muchas veces esta en el borde ya que en ciertos casos es una respuesta retórica como en tu caso. En esos casos yo siempre uso el principio de buena fe por lo que me pregunto: ¿con lo qué señala se podria solucionar el problema? Y pues parece que en este caso en particular sí. Solo considero que son comentarios aquellas respuestas que claramente lo son, por ejmplo los que solo piden codigo o recomendaciones de como usar el sitio.

Comment: Es muy interesante tu comentario, sobre todo considerar _la frontera_ entre "puede ser la solución o no". En mi defensa, repito lo mismo que dije en la pregunta: Hay comentarios mucho mejor elaborados y, en mi opinión, fueron los que ayudaron a OP a solucionar el problema. Al final, definitivamente, me quedo con la respuesta de Pikoh, es muy esclarecedora y proporciona argumentos válidos, sin dejar lugar a dudas, sobre su acertada decisión de rechazar el reporte.

Comment: @Triby Yo no te estoy acusando de nada por lo que no tienes que defenderte de nada. Mi intención con mi respuesta y comentario es mostrar varios criterios que no son explicitos(o no estan claros o no estas escritos como casos) que la comunidad más veterana tiene.

Comment: @Triby Por ejemplo veo que en SOes hay un abuso de la bandera *muy baja calidad* o *no es una respuesta* para indicar problemas de calidad. Los casos en que los moderadores diamantados tienen que intervenir son contados y deben ser la última opción(es decir cuando el error sea muy claro o no haya como solucionarlo por los miembros de la comunidad) ya que el gran moderador del sitio es la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor no tomes a mal mis comentarios, hay algunas expresiones coloquiales que tenemos los de "la vieja escuela", en ningún momento me he sentido atacado, me disculpo por la confusión. Llevo años participando en comunidades y aún no acabo de acostumbrarme al "modo texto". En verdad agradezco tanto tu respuesta como los comentarios, que sirven mucho para comprender mejor el funcionamiento general de SOes, muy diferente a foros y otras comunidades.

Comment: @Triby okay, exactamente: en SO solo eliminamos el contenido insalvable, aquello que no aporta nada, y lo demás se evalua a traves de los votos(UV o DV). Los UV o DV no son malos ya que solo tienen como objetivo señalar que si te gusto o no la publicación, respectivamente

Comment: Creo que el tema de los DV da para mucho, podrían ser útiles si fueran acompañados de comentarios para que el autor sepa lo que hizo mal y pueda evitar incurrir en los mismos errores en el futuro. Lamentablemente, el 99% de las veces son solo un número sin argumento. Prefiero comentar que votar negativo.

Comment: @Triby Eso ya se discutio en otro post recientemente(y muchas pero muchas veces en el pasado) y la conclusión fue que los comentarios a los DV no son obligatorios. Si para ti es necesario el comentario entonces dale el DV y el comentario. No le des mucho peso a los votos en particular sino a su resultado en conjunto, por ejemplo en tu post tu tienes 2 UV y 2 DV que implica que a la mitad le gusto y a la otra no, nada más.

Comment: Sí, creo haber leído algunos de esos temas y más de una vez he estado tentado a crear otro, pero lo he estado postergando, tal vez pensando en que algún día llegaré a entender algo. :-D  Por mi parte, los puntos son solo estadística y la satisfacción que obtengo de participar en este tipo de comunidades es saber que pude ayudar a alguien a resolver un problema. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

En este caso en particular más que el uso de ciertas palabras, me parece que es mejor argumentar, citando la misma fuente, que no todas las preguntas se pueden ni deben responder.

La respuesta en cuestión es:

> Pues que seguramente el problema está en que quieres hacer un execute sobre el campo $email pero puede que no haya ningún $email.

Con respecto al motivo del rechazo del reporte, sólo que los que lo rechazaron te podrán dar sus motivos, pero de todas formas te comparto porqué algunos de estos reportes se podrían rechazar.

Primero, el título el artículo no es "Cómo responder" sino "¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?". Esto es relevante porque el escribir una buena respuesta y el que todas las respuestas que se publiquen sean buenas **es una aspiración** no una condición para publicar una respuesta. Si la respuesta es buena, lo que procede es votar positivo, si no lo es habrá que votar negativo, si es mas o ménos, no se vota. En cuanto a reportar como no es una respuesta, si la respuesta es coherente con lo que se pregunta no se deberá eliminar, sólo votar.

Cabe mencionar que cuando se reporta una respuesta como "No es una respuesta" se pasa al lista de revisión de Publicaciones de baja calidad donde los usuarios con el privilegio correspondiente votán

[image]

Si hay suficientes votos "Se ve bien" el reporte se rechaza. A quienes votan "Eliminación recomendadad"  se les muestra lo siguiente

[image]

En ocasiones cuando me inclino por eliminar una respuesta y quiero dejar un comenatario al autor , pero  ninguno de los comentarios predefinidos se ajusta y la respuesta no hace daño, cambio de opinión y voto por se ve bien pero le doy un voto negativo a la respuesta.

Artículo de ayuda relacionado

- [¿Qué son los reportes rechazados y qué debo hacer con ellos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags)

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión, parece que nos sometemos al criterio de quienes votaron, el problema es unificación de criterios; al menos fuimos dos quienes reportamos como "Esto es comentario... no una respuesta". Por mi parte, no suelo dar votos negativos porque no les encuentro utilidad, salvo una que otra excepción. P.D. Edité la pregunta para actualizar el título del enlace a "cómo elaborar una buena respuesta".

Comment: @Rubén Tenés razón, me confundí, perfectamente podría haber sido un mod y no lo sabría (elimino el comentario anterior para no causar confusión). Lo único que sé es que nadie votó por "Se ve bien" (https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/242849)

Comment: No hay problema @Pollo, digo, se trata de entener que pasa y cómo funciona esta cosa (: Por otro lado ¿cómo sabemos que esa revisión corresponde al reporte realizado por el AP no a otra?

Comment: @Rubén entiendo que es independiente. Hay revisión si cumple con ciertas condiciones (1 reporte por ejemplo), y el resultado de la revisión impacta sobre los reportes activos... Y podemos asegurar que es la única revisión porque es lo que aparece en https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/407704/timeline

Comment: @Pollo tienes razón, el enlace "baja calidad" en el timeline apunta a la revisión en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

Ve a

`https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/n` donde `n` es tu "user" (número de usuario). Ahí se listarán todas las revisiones y se mostrará el motivo de porqué fue rechazado tu reporte.

Para encontrar tu número de usuario en cualquier publicación haz clic en el botón compartir. El número después del último `/` es tu "user". También puedes escribir "user:me" en el buscador y luego de presionar Enter, `me` será remplazado por tu número de usuario. También puedes ir a tu perfil, el número que se muestre entre los dos últimos `/` es tu número de usuario.

No siempre la razón indicada parace "coherente" porque, al igual que con las razones de cierre, usa un texto predeterminado que trata de englobar los casos más comunes.

Como Pollo sugirió en un comentario en mi otra respuesta, podría ser que en este caso se haya rechazado tu reporte porque algún moderador ♦ lo rechazó. Otra hipótesis es que fue rechazado por el sistema porque la respuesta fue aceptada por el OP. No he encontrado una referencia que explique que esto ocurra.

Relacionado

Artículo de ayuda relacionado

- [¿Qué son los reportes rechazados y qué debo hacer con ellos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags)

Comment: Ir directamente a https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current debería funcionar para todos (`/current`/ se sustituye automáticamente por el id del usuario logado.